# Capturing Text Box Value From Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I am attempting to capture the value input from a text box (yes I have verified it has an niput and is not null).  I have a class variable declared to ensure I am associating with the proper form.  However, my syntax never seems to assign the value, it hits the assignment line then jumps up to `PrintPreviewDlg.ShowDialog();` and throws the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   Additional information: Value cannot be null.

This is my syntax

```
public static LiveBait MainInstance { get; set; }

private void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PrintPreviewDialog PrintPreviewDlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
  PrintPreviewDlg.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 300);
  PrintPreviewDlg.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 29);
  PrintPreviewDlg.Name = "PrintPreviewDlg";
  PrintPreviewDlg.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(375, 250);

  PrintPreviewDlg.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
  PrintPreviewDlg.UseAntiAlias = true;

  dynamic PD = CreatePrintDocument();
  PD.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
  PrintPreviewDlg.Document = PD;

  PrintPreviewDlg.ShowDialog();
}

PD CreatePrintDocument()
{
  PD document = new PD();
  document.SetParentCtrl(this);
  document.PrintData.MagRead = MainInstance.txtMagazineRead.Text;

  //More captures here

  return document;
}

class PraDa
{
    public string MagRead;
}
```

Why is my variable never being set and what must I do in order to ensure it is set so that the btn click event will not error?

**EDIT**
COpying to clipboard produced this stack trace

> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: args
>     ParamName=args
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
>          at ProdData.PD.OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\ProdData\PD.cs:line 234
>          at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument._OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
>          at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.PrintLoop(PrintDocument document)
>          at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
>          at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewControl.ComputePreview()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewControl.CalculatePageInfo()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
>          at ProdData.Controls.DrawingStageCtrl.btnPreview_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\Drl.cs:line 889
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at ProdData.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\Program.cs:line 18
>     InnerException:

**Edit 2**
This is the syntax of my method being requested, hopefully this will shed some light onto what the issue is.

```
    protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPrintPage(e);
    int printHeight = 0;
    int printWidth = 0;
    int rightMargin = 0;

    PaperSize ps = default(PaperSize);
    for (int ix = 0; ix <= PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1; ix++)
    {
        if (PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[ix].Kind == PaperKind.A4)
        {
            ps = PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[ix];
            DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
            break;
        }
    }

    DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = PAGE_TOP_MARGIN;
    DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN;
    DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

    var CurrentPageSettings = base.DefaultPageSettings;
    printWidth = CurrentPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Top - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Bottom;
    printHeight = CurrentPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Left - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Right;
    m_leftMargin = CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Left; //X
    rightMargin = CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Top; //Y

    //Create a rectangle printing are for our document
    m_PrintArea = new RectangleF(m_leftMargin, rightMargin, printWidth, printHeight);

    // Get Normal Row Height
    int charactersFitted = 0;
    int linesFilled = 0;
    SizeF TextSize = new SizeF();
    StringFormat textFormat = new StringFormat();
    //Tell it to Alignment Text in its rectangle 
    textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
    textFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
    TextSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("NORMALROW", SUB_HEADING_FONT, m_PrintArea.Size, textFormat, out charactersFitted, out linesFilled);
    m_NormalRowHeight = (int)TextSize.Height + 3; //Row is bigger than text 

    //Draw First Heading
    Rectangle MainHeaderRect = new Rectangle();
    DrawMainHeading(e, LogoRect, ref MainHeaderRect);
    m_iCurrentLocationY = MainHeaderRect.Bottom + (m_NormalRowHeight);

    int LeftSubHeadingWidth = 200;
    m_SubHeaderTextFieldSize = new Size(LeftSubHeadingWidth, m_NormalRowHeight);
    m_TextValuePairSize = new Size(m_SubHeaderTextFieldSize.Width / 30, m_SubHeaderTextFieldSize.Height);

    bool IPN = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MainInstance.txtPN.Text);
    bool IPJN = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MainInstance.txtPJN.Text);
    bool IDt = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MainInstance.dateIDt.Text);
    bool IPB = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MainInstance.txtIPB.Text);
    bool ISS = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MainInstance.txtISS.Text);

    string ST = !IPN ? String.Format("IPN:: ", MainInstance.txtPN.Text) : String.Format("IPN:: ", null);
    string pnt = !IPJN ? String.Format( MainInstance.txtPJN.Text) : String.Format(null);
    string dt = !IDt ? String.Format(MainInstance.dateIDt.Text) : String.Format(null);
    string pbt = !IPB ? String.Format(MainInstance.txtIPB.Text) : String.Format(null);
    string ST = !ISS ? String.Format(MainInstance.txtISS.Text) : String.Format(null);

    m_iCurrentLocationY += (int)(1.5 * m_NormalRowHeight);
    int iAlphaStart_Y = m_iCurrentLocationY;

    DrawSubHeading(e, ST, new Rectangle(new Point(m_leftMargin, m_iCurrentLocationY), m_SubHeaderTextFieldSize), StringAlignment.Near);
    DrawPairsToPage(e, "IPJN: ", pnt, true, m_leftMargin);
    DrawPairsToPage(e, "Date: ", dt, true, m_leftMargin);
    DrawPairsToPage(e, "IPB: ", pbt, true, m_leftMargin);
    DrawPairsToPage(e, "ISS: ", ST, true, m_leftMargin);

    Panel DrawingArea = m_ParentCtrl.GetDrawingArea();
    Bitmap pota = new Bitmap(DrawingArea.Width, DrawingArea.Height);
    m_ParentCtrl.ShowDetails(true);
    foreach (Control c in DrawingArea.Controls)
    {
        c.BringToFront();
    }
    DrawingArea.DrawToBitmap(pota, new Rectangle(0, 0, DrawingArea.Width, DrawingArea.Height));
    foreach (Control c in DrawingArea.Controls)
    {
        c.BringToFront();
    }
    m_ParentCtrl.ShowDetails(false);
    int iDrawingY = iAlphaStart_Y + (5 * m_NormalRowHeight);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pota, new Rectangle(m_leftMargin, iDrawingY, printWidth, printHeight - iDrawingY));
}
}
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: where do you set the MainInstance

Comment: You probably should not be using `dynamic`.

Comment: document is of type PD,  but PrintData isn't a property of the type PD is it?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani - MainInstance is set directly under InitializeComponents();

Comment: @SLaks - how do I give you the stack trace you need?

Comment: Shouldn't dynamic PD = CreatePrintDocument(); be something like var document = CreatePrintDocument();

Comment: @DavidBetteridge - changing it to var makes no difference, error still occurs.

Comment: I assume some of the code is missing.  For example you will need document.PrintData = new PraDa() in the CreatePrintDocument method.

Comment: You can provide the stack-trace by clicking `Copy to clipboard` on exception pop-up in Visual Studio when debugging.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo - thank you - i have updated post to show wthis

Comment: It's saying that the error is on `C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\ProdData\PD.cs:line 234`, inside the `OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)` method. You need to provide the code on that method too, especially around the `String.Format()` call.

Comment: After reading through your question again, I'm wondering : where does you set the value to `MainInstance.txtMagazineRead.Text` ?

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo - updated post with synatx.  I do it in the method I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace tells you exactly where the ArgumentNull exception is:

> C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\ProdData\PD.cs:line 234

And it also tells you it is in a call to `String.Format`

My [orbuculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_ball)  makes me believe it is on this line (formatted for readability):

```
string ST = !IPN ? 
            String.Format("IPN:: ", MainInstance.txtPN.Text) :
            String.Format("IPN:: ", null);
```

The [documenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) lists those exceptions as well.

There are several things wrong with that line.

First of all `String.Format("IPN:: ", null);`  is the cause of your problems and it doesn't make much sense either. Why do you want to format something that is null anyway. Just return the plain string.

Secondly `String.Format("IPN:: ", MainInstance.txtPN.Text)` will not throw but will always output `IPN::` as you forgot to include `{0}` in the format string to indicate where the argument should go.

Lastly `String.Format(null)` will also throw an exception.

I suggest you introduce a helper method so you can replace that whole boolean juggle

```
// takes any Control and return an emtpy string if Text is null or empty
string GetTextOrEmpty(Control ctl)
{
   var txt = ctl.Text; // base implementation of Text doesn't return null
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt)) {
     return String.Empty;
   } else {
     return txt;
   }
}
```

with something more cleanly like this:

```
string ST = String.Format("IPN:: {0}", GetTextOrEmpty(MainInstance.txtPN));
string pnt = GetTextOrEmpty(MainInstance.txtPJN.Text);
string dt = GetTextOrEmpty(MainInstance.dateIDt.Text);
string pbt = GetTextOrEmpty(MainInstance.txtIPB.Text);
string ST = GetTextOrEmpty((MainInstance.txtISS.Text);
```

That will solve your ArgumentNull Exception for parameter args and as well for parameter format but that one you still had to encounter.